# Python Inheritance Error

Tags: python

I am tring to print self.row with display function. However, the error says There is no no such self.row attribute when it is clearly in the class member.

Please can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

thanks.

```
from Grid import Grid

class Matrix(Grid):
    def _init__(self, m, n, value=None):
        Grid.__init__(m, n)
        self.row = m
        self.col = n
    def display(self):
        print self.row
```

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a '_' on your init call.  It should be:

```
def __init__(self, m,n,value=None):
    ^
    +-- this character is missing.
```

Comment: @user1047092, you can mark the answer as solved by clicking the checkmark to the left.